# If you fail or If you failed

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, tense, difference

> If you fail to prove, manager will fire you.
>   If you failed to prove, manager will fire you.

Which sentence is more appropriate for a scenario where the speaker is warning someone that they risk being fired ***if they fail in the future***?

Comment: What ***is*** the scenario? Is the speaker warning someone that they risk being fired if ***in the future*** they fail to do something? Or does the speaker not yet know whether the addressee ***already*** failed? *(If we discover that you **did** fail, you will be fired, but if you **didn't** fail, you've nothing to worry about)*

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's a warning.

Comment: By the way, to be correct English "manager" requires a determiner (an article like a or the, or a possessive like "your"). To be good English, "prove" requires a object (such as "if you you fail to prove your value")

Comment: Instead of using "prove" by itself (it requires something as DJClayworth said) you can say *"If you fail to perform"*.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is a question that ought to be exemplified by **improve** rather than **prove**. Then the question simply wants an indication of proper sequence of tenses: if you fail to improve, you will be fired.

Answer (score 1):

`if you fail` is probably the form you want.

`failed` implies past tense, that it has already happened, but can also be correct.

Correct examples of `fail`:

> If you fail to explain to me where those coffee cups went, I will fire you.

But also one for `failed`:

> If you failed to explain to Jeff yesterday where those coffee cups went, he will fire you.

Comment: very confusing !!!

Comment: @RashedulAlam It is confusing, yes. Can you think of something I can explain that would make it clearer?